# Error: Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'datetime'

Tags: matlab

I am working in MatLab and have this script that calls an excel file and then converts them into MatLab form.

```
Data=csvread('Group1LoadData.csv',1,0,[1,0,161675,21]);  %Loads the data from a csv file
date=Data(:,1)';
salePrice=Data(:,2)';
fuelCost=Data(:,3)';
Demand=Data(:,4)';
totalProd=Data(:,5)';
SteamSold=Data(:,6)';
turbine1Prod=Data(:,7)';
turbine1Fuel=Data(:,8)';
turbine1CO=Data(:,9)';
turbine1Nox=Data(:,10)';
turbine2Prod=Data(:,11)';
turbine2Fuel=Data(:,12)';
turbine2CO=Data(:,13)';
turbine2Nox=Data(:,14)';
db1Fuel=Data(:,15)';
db1Steam=Data(:,16)';
db2Fuel=Data(:,17)';
db2Steam=Data(:,18)';
steamProd=Data(:,19)';
steamFuel=Data(:,20)';
natGasDensity=Data(:,21)';
temp=Data(:,22)';
date=datetime(date,'ConvertFrom','excel');
```

What I am trying to do is create a new variable called "FuelCost" by calling the data from "fuelCost" in the previous code but only using specific dates, as shown.

```
% Group1BEclcs
tStart=date(:,40746);
tEnd=date(:,43635);
date_use=(tStart:tEnd);
FuelCost=fuelCost(:,(date_use));
```

However, I keep getting an error displaying

"Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'datetime'."

What exactly does this mean?

Comment: The excel file I am calling is called Group1LoadData.csv

Answer (score 2):

The variable `date` is a vector of [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html) types, and you can't use a `datetime` type as an index for another array. It appears that you want to select all date values from index `40746` to `43635`, so you can just select that same set of indices for your `fuelCost` vector:

```
FuelCost = fuelCost(:, 40746:43635);
```

If you have a set of starting and ending date values `tStart` and `tEnd`, you can find a logical index for values in `date` that fall within this range, then index `fuelCost` with it:

```
index = (date >= tStart) & (date <= tEnd);
FuelCost = fuelCost(:, index);
```

Comment: I put in those values just as a holding place. Those values will be changing because I will have to check several dates. How would I go about doing it just based off of tStart and tEnd?